# What is the purpose and benefit of cloning a event in Java

Tags: java, events, event-handling, clone

I'm looking for some feedback/insight into the use of Javas ability to clone events.

```
/*create an eventhandler for the mouse click when on the imagetoview
 * This event handler is bound to the mouse_clicked event
 */
imagetoview.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    //define a public override to set the functionality of the new 
    //mouse click event handler
    @Override public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
        Object clone = e.clone();
    }
});
```

Why would I use this ability if i can access all of the event data from the original?

Comment: It would come in handy when you would need to create a duplicate or "clone" of the original event. But if you're asking why events implement `Clonable`, your guess is as good as mine. You're assuming that **you** would be the one cloning the events, but it could be (and is more likely) that it implements `Clonable` because events are cloned extensively in internal code. It's also possible that there's no reason. The cloning functionality in Java is pretty broken.